# NodeJS push queue, consumed by Laravel worker

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, queue

I'm trying to consume messages sent to SQS by a Node App. So the "push" action is performed by Node App on the server A, the "listen" action by Laravel App on server B.

My problem: I don't know how to format the payload to be consumed with `php artisan queue:work`.

Has anyone experienced this before and found a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it! After some tests I finally menage to read messages from the queue.

Basically, the payload must have a **job** property with the class responsible for executing the work and a **data** property with the actual data. Something like:

```
var payload = {
        job: 'App\\Jobs\\MyTestJob@handle',
        data: {user: foo, email: bar@example.com}
    };
```

Then the payload will be encoded to json string and sent to SQS.

On Laravel side the Job class look like this:

```
public function handle($job, $data){}
```

The queue handler will automatically decode and inject the properties on the method specified in the payload.job. If no method is specified Laravel will try to run ::fire() method.

Comment: I understand that this solution is pretty old and it's not working anymore for me on Laravel 5.3 Do you have any idea on how to still get it working? Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465455/push-to-laravel-queue-from-outside-laravel-nodejs?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: FYI, this still works for me on Laravel 5.4. 

Edit: However, it doesn't remove jobs from the queue, so it doesn't completely solve the issue.